# Adding quick parts to a XWPFParagraph in POI

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I am generating Word files from a Word template (dotx) with the POI framework.
Works nice, but now I am searching for a possibility to use the functionality of adding predefined **Building blocks (Quick parts)** to a paragraph. Is there a possibility to add - like adding a style - building blocks to paragraphs with POI? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality does not currently exist. If you would like to develop such a functionality, and contribute it, create a bug and a patch in the POI  bugzilla. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?list_id=158517&product=POI

I suspect this will be non-trivial as the **Quick parts** are stored in a template in the glossary part (which itself is not yet supported). So you would need to add glossary support as well as support for retrieving building blocks from the template and, and then adding them to the document in the appropriate location.